# d3js v3: Selecting a Node on click

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I think I don't understand how D3 works with its Nodes.

I'm loading a JSON file (hierarchical Array):

```
d3.json('readme.json', function(error, data){
    nodes = tree.nodes(data);
```

And I'm appending groups (and rects and other svg objects) into a svg container:

```
var gNodes = svgContainer
    .selectAll(".node")
    .data(nodes)
    .enter()
        .append("g")
        .attr("transform", "translate("+2000+","+0+")")
        .on("click", toggle);
```

What I want to do now is hiding a node's children by clicking on a node (which has a size which is visible via rect svg object) but I could not manage to get it to work.

I have a function toggle:

```
function toggle(d)
```

Which is used via click on the node (see `var gNodes` above).

In toggle I can use `d.children` and via debugger I can see that he finds the correct nodes.

But how can I remove the nodes and the rects and so on in the svgContainer? it doesn't work like this:

```
d.children.exit().remove();
```

I think this `.exit().remove()` would work on a selection and `d.children` is not a selection (it is the data inside it?).

But there has to be a way to remove the children of a node in a tree with D3. How can I do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two things:

1. You are correct: `d` here refers to the datum, not to the selection (and also not to the DOM element)
2. `exit()` depends on the DOM element having no datum. All the elements here have data. Therefore, use `remove()` alone.

Since you didn't posted your running code, I'll base my answer in this example from [Mike Bostock](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4339184).

You can select the DOM element based on its datum by filtering a selection. In D3 v4, you can use `node.descendants()` to get all the descendants of the node (`children` will get only the **direct** descendants), filtering the `node` selection itself, and then removing the elements:

```
node.on("click", function(d) {
    node.filter(function(e) {
        return d.descendants().splice(1).indexOf(e) > -1
    }).remove();
})
```

Here is the modified bl.ocks, click on the nodes: https://bl.ocks.org/anonymous/269149545ba97c2c0b20c1c2ea0a91d8/72df7ad28935168f07cc33a92f31752849779378

PS: I'm removing only the nodes, not the links.

PPS: *remove* is different from *hide*. You have to decide what do you want to do with the DOM element.

Comment: Hi, thank you, that is close, but I forgot to say that I'm still working with d3js v3 :( seems there is no descendants() function on a node in this version? Debugger says node.descendants() is not a function)

Comment: You didn't forget to say, it's right there in the title. Just leave the question here for some time to see if someone writes a v3 answer.

Answer (score 1):

Refer:
http://jsfiddle.net/pdj80L43/

```
function click(d)
{
    if (d.children){
        d._children = d.children;
        d.children = null;
    } 
    else{
        d.children = d._children;
        d._children = null;
    }
    update(d);
}

function dblClick(d) {
    columnAttribute.push(d.name);
    console.log(columnAttribute);
}
function collapse(d){
    if (d.children){
        d._children = d.children;
        d._children.forEach(collapse);
        d.children = null;
    }
}
```

This works excellent! Removes all links & collapses the subtree.